# save Inkcanvas control content as pdf

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, pdf-generation, inkcanvas

I want to save the output of InkCanvas control as PDF file I can save it as .isf and .bmp and I want to save it as .pdf how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download PDF library from [pdfsharp-codeplex](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/)
or [pdfsharp.net](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)
and check the graph sample image section 
so you can first save it as .jpg then save it as pdf

Answer (score 2):

### //First of all create multiple instance of Ink Canvas and add in List** and then save in PDF one canvas have one image.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("[{Scene}]Strokes:{Strokes.Count}, Children:{Children.Count}")]
public class InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav : InkCanvas
{
}
public List<InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav> listCanvas = new List<InkCanvas_SandeepJadhav>();

      public void saveMultiInkCanvasToPdf()
        {
            string subpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();          
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog12 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog12.Filter = "Pdf File|*.pdf";
            saveFileDialog12.Title = "Save Pdf File";
            saveFileDialog12.InitialDirectory = subpath;
            saveFileDialog12.ShowDialog();
            // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.  
            if (saveFileDialog12.FileName == "") return;
            subpath = saveFileDialog12.FileName.Substring(0, saveFileDialog12.FileName.Length - saveFileDialog12.SafeFileName.Length);

            string extension = saveFileDialog12.FileName.Remove(subpath.IndexOf(subpath), subpath.Length);
            string[] allStr = extension.Split('.');

            if (allStr[1] == "pdf")
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog12.FileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                    document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                    if (!document.IsOpen())
                        document.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listCanvas.Count; i++)
                    {
                        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)listCanvas[i].Width, (int)listCanvas[i].Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
                        rtb.Render(listCanvas[i]);
                        // draw the ink strokes onto the bitmap
                        DrawingVisual dvInk = new DrawingVisual();
                        DrawingContext dcInk = dvInk.RenderOpen();
                        dcInk.DrawRectangle(listCanvas[i].Background, null, new Rect(0d, 0d, listCanvas[i].Width, listCanvas[i].Height));
                        foreach (System.Windows.Ink.Stroke stroke in listCanvas[i].Strokes)
                        {
                            stroke.Draw(dcInk);
                        }
                        dcInk.Close();

                        //save bitmap to file                          
                        MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
                        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder encoder1 = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                        encoder1.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
                        encoder1.Save(fs);
                        byte[] tArr = fs.ToArray();
                        fs.Close();

                        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(tArr);
                        image.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width - 10, document.PageSize.Height - 10);//Resize image depend upon your need
                        document.Add(image);
                        document.NewPage();
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    document.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Needs explanation ! Don't just copy paste code please.

Comment: i just replied how to save multiple inkcanvas in one pdf file. i rendered inkcanvas in MemoryStream  and then that MemoryStream  added in Image Object and each image object written in document object.

Comment: if you face any problem. let me know.

Comment: and above whole code created by me only. not copy paste.

Comment: Thank you for your code! I'm new, and I don't really know how to try your code on my project. Could you provide an example of how to use it, please? Thank you.